# Neo4j: Finding simple path between two nodes takes a lot of time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j: Finding simple path between two nodes takes a lot of time even after using upper limit (*1..4). I don't want to use allShortestPath or shortestPath because it doesnt return all the paths.

```
Match p=((n {Name:"Node1"}) -[*1..4]-> (m {Name:"Node2"})) return p;
```

Any suggestions to make it faster ?

Comment: Do you need all the paths or just one? In case of the latter, just use `LIMIT 1` when returning.

Comment: No i need all the possible paths otherwise i could have used shortestPath

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of nodes, try creating an index so that the neo4j DB engine does not have to search through every node to find the ones with the right `Name` property values.

I am presuming that, in your example, the `n` and `m` nodes are really the same "type" of node. If this is true, then:

1. Add a label (I'll call it 'X') to every node (of the same type as `n` and `m`). You can use the following to add the 'X' label to node(s) represented by the variable `n`. You'd want to precede it with the appropriate MATCH clause:

   SET n:X
2. Create an index on the `Name` property of nodes with the `X` label like this:

   CREATE INDEX ON :X(Name);
3. Modify your query to:

   MATCH p=((n:X {Name:"Node1"}) -[*1..4]-> (m:X {Name:"Node2"}))
   RETURN p;

If you do the above, then your query should be faster.

Comment: Node1 and Node2 are not of the same type but i will try your suggestion by creating labels and indexes on the nodes.

Comment: yeah this makes it quite fast. Thanks cybersam.

Comment: Bro you are awesome. Thanks!